# foreach for JSON array , syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

my script is getting some array from php server side script.

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

now I want to check each variable of the array.

```
if (result.a!='') { something.... }
if (result.b!='') { something.... }
....
```

Is there any better way to make it quick like in php 'foreach' , 'while' or smth ?

**UPDATE**

This code ( thanks to hvgotcodes ) gives me values of variables inside the array but how can I get the names of variables also ?

```
for(var k in result) {
   alert(result[k]);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how php side works

```
$json = json_encode(array("a" => "test", "b" => "test",  "c" => "test", "d" => "test"));
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you can access the attributes of each JSON Object by using it's name, like you would a property. e.g. `JSONObject.name` to get the attribute inside JSONObject that holds `{'name':'foo'}`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can do something like

```
for(var k in result) {
   console.log(k, result[k]);
}
```

which loops over all the keys in the returned json and prints the values.  However, if you have a nested structure, you will need to use

```
typeof result[k] === "object"
```

to determine if you have to loop over the nested objects.  Most APIs I have used, the developers know the structure of what is being returned, so this is unnecessary.  However, I suppose it's possible that this expectation is not good for all cases.

Comment: you're going to want to square-bracket that. Edit: you fixed it.

Comment: yeah i actually made sure by trying in the console. ;)

Comment: that works. but 1 more problem, how can I get the names of those variables inside array ?

Comment: @david, is it an array, or an object literal?

Comment: @david, updated the answer -- `k` is the key, result[k] is the value.

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
$.each(result,function(index, value){
    console.log('My array has at position ' + index + ', this value: ' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the .forEach() method of JavaScript for looping through JSON.

```js
var datesBooking = [
    {"date": "04\/24\/2023"},
      {"date": "04\/25\/2023"}
    ];
    
    datesBooking.forEach(function(data, index) {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

Sure, you can use JS's foreach.

```
for (var k in result) {
  something(result[k])
}
```