# How to check whether all the key & value of a JS Object exist in the another JS object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Suppose there are two JavaScript objects.

`first = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];`

`second= [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];`

What I actually want that if all the key and value of `second` JSON Object exist in `first` JSON Object then it will return `match = true` or `true` else it will return `match = false` or `false`.

**Note: The value of `first` and `second` will change dynamically and its index too**

**I have to do this in ES**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662997/foreach-for-json-array-syntax

Comment: Actually I know the loops but I want to do it in a simple way. I was using $.each to access the key and values but after that, I am a little bit confused

Comment: Don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON.

Comment: Actually I posted there JSON by mistake, Sorry my fault Now I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const second = [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}]
const first = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"}, {valueFour: "DescFour"}];

const res = second.every((i) => (
  first.find(j => JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(j))
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `every` on `second` array and use `Object.entries` to extract key and value, then check if it is present in the first array.

```js
const second = [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}]
const first = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"}, {valueFour: "DescFour"}];

const output = second.every((obj) => {
    const [secondKey, secondVal] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
    return first.some((obj) => {
        const [firstKey, firstVal] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
        return firstKey == secondKey && firstVal == secondVal;
    });
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is working fine but can you please help it convert in ES5 as I can't use ES6 .

Comment: @AyushSrivastava - You can use `babel` for that - https://babeljs.io/en/repl.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack to achieve the same:

```
let arr1 = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];

let arr2 = [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];

arr1 = arr1.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
arr2 = arr2.map(x => JSON.stringify(x));

console.log(arr1);

console.log(arr2);


let intersection = arr1.filter(value => arr2.includes(value));
intersection = intersection.map(x => JSON.parse(x));

console.log(intersection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var first = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];
var second= [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];
var firstObjKeys = [], firstObjValues = [];
var secondObjKeys = [], secondObjValues = [];


first.forEach(element => Object.keys(element).forEach(function(key) { 
 firstObjKeys.push(key);
 firstObjValues.push(element[key]);
}));

second.forEach(item => Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) { 
 secondObjKeys.push(key);
 secondObjValues.push(item[key]);
}));

if (JSON.stringify(firstObjKeys.sort()) !== JSON.stringify(secondObjKeys.sort())
 || JSON.stringify(firstObjValues.sort()) !== JSON.stringify(secondObjValues.sort())) {
 console.log('not equal');
} else {
 console.log('equal');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How about this:

```js
var first = [{valueOne: "DescOne"},{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueThree: "DescThree"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];
var second= [{valueTwo: "Desctwo"},{valueFour: "DescFour"}];
var firstObjKeyStr = '', secondObjKeyStr = '';
var firstObjValueStr = '', secondObjValueStr = '';
var firstObjKeys = [], firstObjValues = [];
var secondObjKeys = [], secondObjValues = [];


first.forEach(element => Object.keys(element).forEach(function(key) { 
 firstObjKeys.push(key);
 firstObjValues.push(element[key]);
}));
firstObjKeyStr = JSON.stringify(firstObjKeys.sort());
firstObjValueStr = JSON.stringify(firstObjValues.sort());

second.forEach(item => Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) { 
 secondObjKeys.push(key);
 secondObjValues.push(item[key]);
}));
secondObjKeyStr = JSON.stringify  (secondObjKeys.sort());
secondObjValueStr = JSON.stringify(secondObjValues.sort());

if (firstObjKeyStr !== secondObjKeyStr || firstObjValueStr !== secondObjValueStr) {
 console.log('not equal');
} else {
 console.log('equal');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```